# How to organize App.config files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have console application and want to organize App.config files for different builds in such a way when particular build has been created, the appropriate config file should be copied to its folder.

There's a build named - ReleaseProduction. I've created the three with a main App.config file as a root and App.ReleaseProduction.config file as a subtype.

The App.ReleaseProduction.config file looks as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration  xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    ...
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

There's a section in project's csproj file that looks as following:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="App.config">
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  </None>
  <None Include="App.ReleaseProduction.config">
    <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
<Target Name="AfterCompile" Condition="Exists('App.$(Configuration).config')">
  <TransformXml Source="App.config" Transform="App.$(Configuration).config" Destination="App.config" StackTrace="true" />
</Target>
```

But, I've got this error message:

```
Exception: Не удалось записать конечный файл: Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "D:\SVN\Concert\trunk\SitemapBuilder\App.config", так как этот файл используется другим процессом.
   в Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.TransformXml.SaveTransformedFile(XmlTransformableDocument document, String destinationFile)
   в Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.TransformXml.Execute()
IOException: Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "D:\SVN\Concert\trunk\SitemapBuilder\App.config", так как этот файл используется другим процессом.
   в System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   в System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   в System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   в System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
   в System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   в System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding)
   в Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.XmlAttributePreservingWriter..ctor(String fileName, Encoding encoding)
   в Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.XmlFileInfoDocument.Save(String filename)
   в Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.TransformXml.SaveTransformedFile(XmlTransformableDocument document, String destinationFile)
    D:\SVN\Concert\trunk\SitemapBuilder\ConcertRu.SitemapBuilder.csproj 116 5   ConcertRu.SitemapBuilder
```

Which means the process cannot get access to this file "D:\SVN\Concert\trunk\SitemapBuilder\App.config" because it's used by another process.

How to overcome this issue?